# After i paste data on an excel sheet can i use excel macro recorder to replicate it every time? even if the data isn't in the clipboard anymore

Tags: vba, excel, macros

if I use the macro recorder it just pastes from the clipboard and if the data isn't in the clipboard it doesn't work anymore. any suggestion how to overcome this?

I’ll be more specific I think the question is a bit vague.

every time I create a new workbook [I'm using VBA to do this]
I need to add the tile rows and some columns that have data.

so every new workbook I create needs to have this.

how should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim currWorkBook As Workbook, newWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim currentWorkSheet As Worksheet, newWorkSheet As Worksheet

    Set currWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set currentWorkSheet = currWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set newWorkBook = Workbooks.Add

    With newWorkBook
        Set newWorkSheet = newWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .SaveAs Filename:="E:\Test\Book2.xls", FileFormat:=56         'FileFormat:=56 will save file as 97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls
        'range to copy
        currentWorkSheet.Range("1:1").Copy 'this will copy the first row i.e. title row
        'paste copied range
        newWorkSheet.Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        'another range to copy
        currentWorkSheet.Range("D:D").Copy   'sample to show copying of column "D", you can write your range here
        'paste another copied range
        newWorkSheet.Range("D1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup exactly what i wanted! I was confused on how to keep switching between workbooks. Just a beginner here. thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

*After i paste data on an excel sheet can i use excel macro recorder to replicate it every time?* - No.  A recorded Paste will paste whatever is in the clipboard at the time it is run.

To answer your real question - write code to create the specific headers you need

Eg

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1) = "My Header"
        ' etc
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: there are a lot of cells ( hundreds of them ) so this will be very time consuming

Comment: is there any other workaround?

Comment: writing to "hundreds" of cells will execute in a blink of the eye.

Comment: i'm sure there is a better way; thanks for the input though ^^